# Evaluating the convolution integral of two sine functions

Tags: integration, convolution

This is a homework problem, so I'm not looking for a worked out solution, merely to be pointed in the right direction.

Convolve x(t) with h(t) where:

$$
x(t) = sin(t) \\
h(t) = e^{-.1t}sin(2t)u(t)
$$

u(t) is the unit step function.  Here is where I got:

$$
y(t) =  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} sin(t - \tau)e^{-.1\tau}sin(2\tau)u(\tau) \, d\tau
$$

$$
y(t) =  \int^{\infty}_{0} sin(t - \tau)e^{-.1\tau}sin(2\tau)\, d\tau
$$

At this point I'm pretty lost, I don't recognize any normal techniques of integration that can handle this.  After applying some trig identities I get:

$$
y(t) =  \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-.1\tau}cos(t - \tau) \, d\tau - \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-.1\tau}cos(t) \, d\tau
$$

This seems a little better(I can evaluate the second integral), but I'm still lost on the first.  I'd appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(t-\tau)\sin(2\tau)
&=\frac{\cos(t-3\tau)-\cos(t+\tau)}{2}\\
&=\frac{\cos(t)\cos(3\tau)+\sin(t)\sin(3\tau)}{2}\\
&-\frac{\cos(t)\cos(\tau)-\sin(t)\sin(\tau)}{2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\cos(ax)\,e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac1b\int_0^\infty\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-bx}\\
&=\frac1b-\frac ab\int_0^\infty\sin(ax)\,e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\sin(ax)\,e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac1b\int_0^\infty\sin(ax)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-bx}\\
&=\frac ab\int_0^\infty\cos(ax)\,e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(ax)\,e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\tag{4}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty\sin(ax)\,e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Change of variable in the first integral might help.